# Socket.io firing multiple events 3 times

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

If I start the server and one one client connects all the functions firing 3 times. I don't konw how to stop this.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

  weatherFiveDay.getFiveDayWeatherData(function(result) {
    socket.emit('weatherFiveDay', result);
  });

  //Übertrage Daten zur Anzeige des aktuellen Wetters
  weatherAPI.getActualWeather(function(result) {
    socket.emit('weather', result);
  });

  //Übertrage Daten zur Anzeige des PV-Leistung
  mysqlDaten.get5DaysPVData(function(result) {
    socket.emit('powerForecast', result);
  });

  //Übertrage Daten zur Anzeige des Wettervorhersage
  forecastAPI.get5DayForecast(function(result) {
    socket.emit('weatherForecast', result);
  });

});
```

Client example:

```
var socket = io.connect();
    socket.on('weatherFiveDay', function (data) {
});
```

Comment: If you add `console.log(socket.id)` inside the `connection` handler, does it fire three times as well?

Comment: HI, i added it after:  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

        console.log(socket.id);                            and it fires three times.

Comment: That would mean that the client is connecting three times. Is your client code being started inside an event handler of some sorts?

Comment: I think my problem is, that i have 3 client.js files. Each of the client.js is calling io.connect() . Is that the problem? @robertklep

Comment: How can I store io.connect() globally?

Comment: It's not a _problem_, but it doesn't seem useful. You could just store it as a sort-of-global variable: `if (! window._socket) window._socket = io()`.

Comment: Any solution found?